# Import csv file into mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql, csv, character-encoding, import

i trying to import csv file into mysql database using php but the Arabic text doesn't shown,
i use 
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8;");

mysql_query("SET CHARACTER_SET utf8;");

but its still not working...

Comment: are your table and column and connection set to utf8 ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the database table column's "COLLATION" for the UTF-8 characters.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-column.html

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET charset_name [COLLATE collation_name];
```

Comment: my table COLLATION is utf8_bin

Comment: Pleas share table structure.

Comment: the problem is when fetching the data from csv file because if you trying to insert arabic text from php using mysql query, its works good

Comment: Then please try to save CSV file as UTF-8.